# retrieve minted NFT's by a wallet address - OpenSea

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, opensea

According to openSea api we use [Retrieving events](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-asset-events)
Under `event_type` We found `The event type to filter. Can be created for new auctions, successful for sales, cancelled, bid_entered, bid_withdrawn, transfer, or approve`

My question here is how to find minted ones ?

IE: This wallet  [Unnamed](https://opensea.io/0xf733278fbe8e3ceaffb5838dd32a5c598c22b066) minted this token : [Vortex #838](https://opensea.io/assets/0xa7d8d9ef8d8ce8992df33d8b8cf4aebabd5bd270/225000838)

My Goal is to get list of all NFT's minted by specific user.

Answer (score 2):

I think collectibles is the same as NFT(ERC 721) so Try this

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=your_wallet_address&offset=0&limit=300

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).